# CF with Workbench not loading in WinUAE but works on real A1200

Tags: amiga-1200, amiga-workbench-3.1

I have a CF HDD with installed WB3.1, which works as expected on real A1200. Yesterday I wanted to copy over the latest ACA1221 soft, took the CF out, connected to PC just as normal. The WinUAE is set up exactly as my A1200 (without aca) and in fact is set up exactly the same way that allowed me to install WB in the first place.

WorkBench loads in WinUAE from CF, the WB window shows after the  boot, with all the icons, but the clock cursor icon remains on the screen (betterWB, MUI, etc. Not loading). If left like this it will be in this state forever, not loading fully, but only on WinUAE.

WinUAE uses rom dumped from my licensed chip.

Is there any way to fix it? I just need to copy over few files. I don't want to reinstall WB if I don't have to.

Comment: What ROMs do you load in WinUAE - Probably not the same as on real hardware?

Comment: Good point, line added on this one, it's the same one

Comment: You sure "will be in this state forever"? Maybe it's just waiting in a timeout for a non-existing (non-emulated) piece of hardware.

Comment: To my best knowledge yes, I have removed ACA lines from startup-sequence before removing the CF. Left it overnight, no success

Comment: Just to copy over to the CF, you don't actually need to boot from it. Boot UAE into a known good image and attach the CF as an external drive.

Comment: please check the contents of "wbstartup" directory. There could be startup programs for hardware that you don't have on your winuae setup